# Por que me sale [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, array

Hola buenas tardes estoy intentando imprimir un arreglo y cuando le doy click al botón que debería de mostrarme el arreglo en una tabla solo me sale "[object Object]"
me pueden ayudar por favor, les envío el código.
Función para imprimir en mi tabla

```
  var basedeDatos=[];
    function agregar(){
      basedeDatos.push(ORDER);
      var data =_.orderBy (basedeDatos,[ 'M1','F1' ] ,  [ 'asc','asc']);         
      document.getElementById('listaElementos2').innerHTML +=
      '<td>'+data+'</td>'


    }
```

Arreglo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado obtenido:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que realmente hace `_.orderBy (basedeDatos,[ 'M1','F1' ] ,  [ 'asc','asc'])` ?

Comment: Ordena la variable M1 que contiene (Máquinas 1) ascendentemente al igual que F1 que contiene algunas sumas.

Comment: Basicamente ocurre porque estas enviando un objecto al html, es decir, no estas accendiendo a las propiedades del array y por eso se envia el objecto COMPLETO.

Comment: Es exacto lo que dice @Ivandez pensé que realmente tu funcion de `_.orderBy` te retornaba algún valor pero lo que realmente necesitas mandarle a tu `td` es un string y no un objeto

Comment: y como hago para no enviar el objeto completo?

Comment: podria poner ORDER.nombre o algo asi?

Comment: Puedes acceder a las propiedades de tus objetos utilizando el `.` (punto) como por ejemplo `'<td>'+data.nombre+'</td>'` desconosco como es la estructura de tu objeto pero practicamente la sitaxis es la misma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que hacer un ciclo en tus datos:

```js
let cadena = ''
data.forEach(maquina => {
      cadena += '<tr>'
      cadena += '<td>' + maquina.nombre + '</td>'
      cadena += '<td>' + maquina.F2 + '</td>'
      cadena += '</tr>'
    }
    
document.getElementById('listaElementos2').innerHTML = cadena
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó