# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar todo el contenido de un array de objetos en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, javascript-objeto

Tengo este array de objetos, pero no se como mostrar todos los objetos de este array con sus valores... Poder mostrarlo en el documento HTML, al hacer un bucle for, solo me imprime "object[Object]" con todos los objetos que hay dentro del array, pero al hacerlo por consola, me lo imprime.... Mi intención es mostrar el contenido del array de objetos en mi documento HTML

```js
    let piratas = [
  { Nombre: "Alex", Apellido: "Jimenez", Edad: 21 },
  { Nombre: "David", Apellido: "Delgado", Edad: 25 },
  { Nombre: "Paco", Apellido: "Delgado", Edad: 54 },
  { Nombre: "Ana", Apellido: "Jimenez", Edad: 50 }
];
```

---

De mostrar en el documento HTML, al hacer un bucle for, solo me imprime object[Object] con todos los objetos que hay dentro del array, pero al hacerlo por consola, me lo imprime.... Mi intención es mostrar el contenido del array de objetos en mi documento HTML

Comment: mostrar donde?  en una página html o en la consola?  para verlo en la consola simplemente escribe `console.log(piratas)` en el código y ejecútalo... para verlo en un HTML mejor que lo recorras en un bucle y agreges su contenido al HTML que desees y lo pongas en un elemento para mostrar

Comment: Hola Alex, te recomiendo leer [ask] y completar el [tour]. La pregunta necesita más detalles de lo que estás intentando.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Por que me sale \[object Object\]?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495051/por-que-me-sale-object-object)

Answer (score 0):

A ver espero que esto te ayude te lo saco por `console.log` ya que en la pregutne dices que como sacar cada valor. Te deje un ejemplo en html sacando los nombres y poniendolos en un div
he usado un .map igual creo que puedes usar .forEach
como `piratas` es un `array` principalmente pues lo mapeas y consigues cada dato con cada valor

Por si no sabes que son los `...` delante de `piratas` es el `spread` operador, basicamente estoy asignando a `nombres` una copia del array.
Creas varias variables como nombres, apellidos, y tal y que devuelva solo item.nombres por ejemplo. Ahi es mas como tu quieras el resultado.

```js
let piratas = [
  { Nombre: "Alex", Apellido: "Jimenez", Edad: 21 },
  { Nombre: "David", Apellido: "Delgado", Edad: 25 },
  { Nombre: "Paco", Apellido: "Delgado", Edad: 54 },
  { Nombre: "Ana", Apellido: "Jimenez", Edad: 50 }
];
const datos = [...piratas.map((item, index) => {
  console.log('posicion array:', index, '//',
              'Nombre:', item.Nombre, '//',
              'Apellido:', item.Apellido, '//',
              'item:', item.Edad)
              return item.Nombre
})]

document.getElementById('nombres').innerHTML = datos;
```

```html
<div id='nombres'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que probablemente estes accediendo directamente al objeto y no a sus propiedades, para acceder a las propiedades de un objeto tienes que hacerlo de la siguiente forma: `MyObject.propierty`, de esta forma ya vas estar seleccionando la propieda del objeto.

Abajo dejo un ejemplo de como puedes recorrer el `array` de objetos para poder accerder a sus propiedades y mostrarlas en una tabla.

Y [Aca dejo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) la documentacion de objetos con javascript.

```js
let piratas = [
  { Nombre: "Alex", Apellido: "Jimenez", Edad: 21 },
  { Nombre: "David", Apellido: "Delgado", Edad: 25 },
  { Nombre: "Paco", Apellido: "Delgado", Edad: 54 },
  { Nombre: "Ana", Apellido: "Jimenez", Edad: 50 }
];
let contenido=""
//Recorremos el arreglo de objetos
piratas.map(item=>{
//Accedemos a su contenido
  contenido +=`<tr>
  <td>${item.Nombre}</td>
  <td>${item.Apellido}</td>
  <td>${item.Edad}</td>
  </tr>`
})
//Dibujamos la informacion
document.getElementById("tbodytablepiratas").innerHTML = contenido
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  background-color: #96D4D4;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Nombre</th>
   <th>Apellido</th>
   <th>Edad</th>
  </tr>
<thead>
<tbody id="tbodytablepiratas">

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Y de que otra forma lo podría hacer sin tener que meter código html en el código de javascript?? Es decir, que muestre los valores de los objetos del array, según donde yo le indique, se que se debe hacer con los "id", pero no se de que manera implementarlo para que esto suceda

Comment: De la forma en lo que lo hago en el ejemplo `document.getElementById("tbodytablepiratas").innerHTML = contenido` obtienes el elemento por su id y con innerHtml insertas el contenido en el. De la misma forma puedes hacerlo, claro que si lo haces de esa forma no va a ser dinamico, porque vas a tener que haber creado el elemento en tu html antes de agregarle el contenido.